# how to get time from yyyymmddhhmmss format in javascript

Tags: javascript, slice, tostring

YYYYMMDDHHMMSS FORMAT

```js
var d = new Date("20180101120000");

var k = d.toString().slice(8,10);
var l = d.toString().slice(10,12);
var m = d.toString().slice(12,14);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = k + ":" + l + ":" + m +" " ;
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: You already have the solution? I would turn it into a function though.

Comment: all you have to do is drop 'new Date(' and use it as a string, if you're going to slice it anyway

Comment: when i made alert(d.toString()) ,its showing invalid date

Comment: You should read the [documentation of `new Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: thanks for the help guys,,i got it

Comment: var d = "20180101120000";